# looking to insert date column in write.csv()

Tags: r

I would like to add date field dynamically in `write.csv()` , example

```
write.csv(df,"datefield.CSV")
```

Month field should come from df

```
dataframe:-

Month Name
01     amar
02     nari
```

Output of file should be   `01.csv` and `02.csv`

Answer (score 0):

```
write.csv(df, paste0("df_", Sys.Date(), ".csv"))
```

This saves `df` as `df_{currentdate}.csv` in your current working directory.

## DATA:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Month Name
                 01     amar
                 02     nari", header = T)
```